# Combine scrollview and listview in Android like Wunderlist animation

Tags: android, animation, parallax

I want to create a scroll animation with image on top of listview.
I want that when user scroll listview, image on top scaledown until 50dp of height. Than listview scroll without other anim. When user scroll up until the first item, image scaleup to fit the original size.
This behavior is present in wunderlist profile view and in this link is similar.[pinterest demo](http://it.pinterest.com/pin/392305817515197630/)

Can you help me to create this?

I'm using a scrollview with linearlayout, when user scroll in the scrollview image scaledown, but i'm not able to enable listview scroll.

Answer (score 1):

you should check Android-OberservableScrollView to achieve what you need:

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView